# Is it possible to turn on/off two layers at once with the openlayers_plus module?

Tags: blocks, javascript

Using the BlockSwitcher module that comes with the [openlayers_plus](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers_plus) module, is it possible to create a button that turns on/off two layers at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be to create a function that uses setVisibility()

For example (without toggle logic):

```
$('.my-button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var ol = $('.openlayers-map').data('openlayers');
  ol.openlayers.getLayersByName('myLayerName1')[0].setVisibility(false);
  ol.openlayers.getLayersByName('myLayerName2')[0].setVisibility(false);
});
```

Comment: Great, it works!
If you want to find out the name of the layers use console.log(ol) and have a look at the ol object in the browser console. There you'll find the layer name.